# I can't add an approval workflow to a calendar on my share point site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have all workflow options active on my site collections level, yet the approval workflow still does not appear. I only see Publishing workflow, Disposition Approval workflow, and Three State workflow. I have deactivated and reactivated just about every possible workflow just to make sure it wasn't needing a reset.

Comment: Took a quick look from a site on my O365 instance. the *Approval - SharePoint 2010 workflow is definitely part of the site collection feature "Workflows - Aggregated set of out-of-box workflow features provided by SharePoint. "

Comment: I have the "Workflows-Aggregated set out-of-box workflow" feature activated but it still does not allow me to see Approval - SharePoint 2010 workflow when looking through my workflow options

Comment: Do you see any of the workflows marked as 2010 workflows?

Comment: None of the options specifically have "2010" in the name, but they do have asterisks next to them that 'denote 2010 workflows'

Answer (score 0):

A possibility from https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/051c7bb9-1d42-40b6-a1e2-85fc276e17d3/workflows-in-office-365-sahrepoint?forum=sharepointgeneral:

> I noticed there was a message "You have not enabled Approval
>   workflows" under "Denotes a SharePoint 2010 template" when I created a
>   workflow, like the screenshot below. If I clicked "Activate", all
>   built-in workflow templates showed.

I suppose check for that button and click it if it's there.